# Modifying other users in Angular 6

Tags: firebase, angular6

So I am trying to create an app that has an admin role and anyone with that role should be able to access a front end list of users and enable/disable any user from logging into the app. I am using Angular 6 as the front end and firebase/firestore as the back end (via AngularFire) is there a way I can do this?

I tried adding the firebase admin sdk to the angular app but there seemed to be a lot of issues. Any pointers will help! Thanks!

Comment: No thats not what I need. I am talking about querying the firebase database to modify a user that is not signed in @karoluS

Answer (score 0):

One of the many approaches could be controlling the access of the users via a defined property against each `registered user`

`registered-users /
|--------- user-id-1 /
|             | --- canLogin: <boolean>
|             | --- ...
|
|--------- user-id-2 /
|             | --- canLogin: <boolean>
|             | --- ...
|`

In database rules, restrict the `write` access to the `registered-users` to only 'admin' role.

While authenticating the user, using `AngularFireAuth.authState` - we can `switchMap` to access the `registered-users/<user.uid>` node/doc and based on the boolean value of the `canLogin` field, the user can be force logged out.